# How to setup vpc connector for firebase cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, vpc

Firebase Cloud Functions run on top of GCP, so, do they support using a [vpc connector](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/connecting-vpc)?

What I'm trying to achieve is to limit a forward-proxy server to only accept requests from the internal network, but since Cloud Functions doesn't support static IPs, the only way would be via vpc connector.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cloud Functions for Firebase doesn't actually run "on top of" GCP.  Firebase just adds tools and SDKs that make Cloud Functions easier to use for some developers.  The core Cloud Functions product is exactly the same, no matter if you're building and deploying with Firebase tools or gcloud.

You should still be able to configure a VPC connector for functions deployed with the Firebase CLI.  You will just not able able to configure it on the command line like you can with gcloud.  Instead, you will have to configure the connector in the Cloud console after deploying the function, exactly as described in the documentation you linked to.

Comment: The documentation I linked deploys the function and assigns the vpc connector via command: `gcloud beta functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME \
--vpc-connector projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGION/connectors/CONNECTOR_NAME` how would I do that in the console?

Comment: The documentation is on the page you linked to.  You have to switch away from the gcloud tab to the console tab.

Comment: There's no console tab for the configuring part: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/connecting-vpc#configuring

Comment: View the function in the cloud console, edit it, the expand all the options to see where you can type in the name of the VPC connector for the function.

Comment: When settings VPC connector manually from the GCP console, a new version with updated configuration is deployed. However, next time you deploy using `firebase deploy ...`, the VPC connector is maintained.

To set the VPC connector manually: open function details page -> `EDIT` -> expand `Environment variables, networking, timeouts and more` -> choose `VPC connector` -> `Deploy`

Comment: Unfortunately even a small change(while editing a function) is asking for redeploy of source code which is crazy! I still didn't get why there is a need to redeploy the source code if i just add a vpc connector or an env variable. Earlier it used to consider the deployed code but not anymore.

Comment: @BjørnEgil, this doesn't seem to be true. For me, after setting the VPC connector and deploying again my function, the connector disappears from the Console. :|

Answer (score 19):

This seems now to be handled in latest firebase-tools v8.9.0 version.

> Must be used in conjunction with firebase-functions v3.11.0 or higher

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v8.9.0

```typescript
functions
  .runWith({
    vpcConnector: 'test-connector',
    vpcConnectorEgressSettings: 'PRIVATE_RANGES_ONLY'
  })
  .auth.user()
  .onCreate((user) => user);
```

Comment: Can this be set globally from for example firebase.json? If so, how? I can't find much documentation about it.

Comment: @JoshuaHester I did not found official documentation on that yet. At the time of this answer, the update was really recent.

I did implemented this solution, and I can confirm this works.
We could probably ask Firebase if some official documentation exists on that point.

Comment: @TheQ 
I think this works pretty much with the same logic as the runtime options, like you would do for memory allocation for example.
The only doc I found on that yet is here : 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation

Comment: Here's some official Firebase documentation on this functionality: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/function_builder.functionbuilder#runtimeoptions:-runtimeoptions

Comment: Updating the link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.runtimeoptions#runtimeoptionsvpcconnector

Answer (score 1):

Since Firebase is just a wrapper for Google Cloud Functions, just bypass the Firebase CLI and use the one with more parameters. (Google Cloud CLI)

i.e.

`$ gcloud functions deploy <function_name> --trigger-http --runtime nodejs10 --vpc-connector projects/<your_project_name>/locations/<your-vpc-region>/connectors/<vpc_name> --service-account <your-role-name>`

Source:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc